# How to subclass "float" without implementing its method?

Tags: python, oop, lazy-evaluation

I want to subclass from `float` but don't want it to init soon. I also don't want to explicitly call `float()` for my object.

For example, I don't want to calculate anything before it is required. I want only to do an object that behaves like `float`. Here is how I want to create class:

```py
class MassiveAverage(float):
    def __init__(self, floats: list[float]):
        self.floats = floats

    def __float__(self) -> float:
        return sum(self.floats) / len(self.floats)
```

And this is how I want to use it:

```py
massive_average = MassiveAverage([1.1, 2.2])  # no any calculations
massive_sum = massive_average * 2  # this is were it calculates its float value
```

Comment: There is no `__float__` method to override. You can define `MassiveAverage.__mul__` to define what `massive_average * 2` means.

Comment: The only method invoked by `massive_average * 2` is `__mul__()`, so that's the method you'd have to override.  (And that doesn't do you any good if someone writes `massive_average + 2` instead; you'd end up having to override *everything*, in which case there was no point in subclassing `float`.)

Comment: @jasonharper that is the point of my question - I want my object to behave like float but only implementing conversion to float, no any other methods related to numeric operations. The `__float__` method here I want to be an internal operation that allows my object to converted into float and let superclass do its work with it.

Comment: There is no such hook. `__str__` exists because there is an explicit protocol defining it for use by the `str` type itself. `float` doesn't have anything analogous (and even if it did, `float` still has to be called by *something*). `"foo" + x` doesn't work even if `x.__str__` is defined; only things like `print` are defined to *implicitly* call `str` on its argument(s).

Comment: @chepner I don't really understand you. I don't want any other functionality then my object been float with lazy evaluation. The example `"foo" + x` where x - my object the same as the `"123" + 1.0`. There is defined result - TypeError, since you can't concat str and float. Also, it is `__float__` that can be defined to allow your class be converted into float - `class A: def __float__(_): return 6.0` and `float(A())` will result `6.0` that why I use in my example - tell superclass how my object can be converted, any other operation is up to `float` class

Comment: My point is, only in special cases like `print` does `__str__` get called when you want a `str` value. (I do very little with floating-point arithmetic; I didn't realize `__float__` really did exist.) The same goes for `__float__`; it isn't called implicitly to get a `float` value when one might be needed. (You generally have to be explicitly, because how should Python know if you want `2 + x` to be `2 + x.__float__()` or `2 + x.__int__()` if both are defined?)

Comment: @MaxSmirnov Why not just have a MassiveAverage object with a .get() method with cacheing? That is, you would massive_average.get() * 2. Or, just have a MassiveAverage function that uses an LRU cache.

Comment: @potapeno I want to create object that behaves like float. No external functions, no caching, no any other functionality

Answer (score 2):

For the answer to this question I am going to assume you are already familiar with python's "magic methods". @gftea's answer has a link to the documentation for some of the magic methods if you are not familiar.

You are going to have to manually define each "magic function" `__mul__`, `__add__`, `__sub__`, etc.

```
class MassiveAverage:

    def __init__(self, floats):
        self._avg = sum(floats)/len(floats)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self._avg * other

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self._avg - other
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self._avg + other

    ...
```

But, this doesn't handle your lazy evaluation use case. Instead, we could maintain an internal cache, and on the first time one of these magic methods are evaluated, we could run the average function.

```
class MassiveAverage:

    def __init__(self, floats):
        self._floats = floats
        self._avg = None

    @property
    def avg(self):
        if self._avg is None:
            self._avg = sum(self._floats) / len(self._floats)
        return self._avg
```

Then, we can replace our magic functions and use `self.avg`.

```
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.avg * other
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.avg + other

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.avg - other
    ...
```

Unfortunately, you cannot subclass float in the manner you want. Because you are specifying lazy evaluation, you are fundamentally changing how the methods in the float class work (since they don't need lazy evaluation). You would still have to manually change each magic method.

Comment: Thanks, you are only one who understood what I want. It is sad that I can't do something like lazy evaluation without constructing all numeric methods. The only way I know to implement this is write `lazyfloat` class that calls not `self.value + other` but `self.__float__() + other` where it is returning constant for float and calculated for lazy classes.

Comment: @MaxSmirnov while you could theoretically do something like that, you would be effectively repeating the same steps that I listed above. IMO there aren't many numeric methods you would need to replace (for example, you only need to define `__gt__` and `__eq__` to define all comparisons). For any float class methods (such as is_integer) you would do `self.avg.is_integer()`.

Answer (score 0):

you should overwrite the operator, for example, to overwrite `*`, you can overwrite the `__mul__` method

```
def __mul__(self, float): ...
```

see below for methods can be defined to emulate numeric objects
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=rmul#emulating-numeric-types

Answer (score 0):

`__float__` is used for exactly one purpose: to define the behavior of `float(x)` as `x.__float__()`. There is no *implicit* conversion in an expression like `massive_average * 2`. This could mean any number of things:

```
massive_average.__int__() * 2
massive_average.__float__() * 2
massive_average.__complex__() * 2
massive_avarge.__str__() * 2
```

so Python refuses to guess. It will try `massive_average.__mul__(2)`, and failing that, `(2).__rmul__(massive_average)`, before giving up.

Each of the type-specific "conversion" methods are used only by the corresponding type itself. `print`, for example, does not call `__str__` (directly); it only is defined to call `str` on each of its arguments, and `str` takes care of calling `__str__`.